# C++ Send arguments to exe file

Tags: c++, c

I have a c++ program that I call with the following line:

```
 ./myProgram
```

However, I'd like to send some external variables to the program (this will eventually be called from PHP via the exec() method). I've searched and read that I should use arguments in the following way:

```
 ./myProgram <arguments>
```

However I'm not exactly sure how to use that. Do I separate the arguments by comma if I have more than one, do I need to put type before? And in the C++ file, how do I get these variables?

Can somebody point me to a tutorial for that? Or any other info, code example?
Thanks!

Comment: why are you sending a binary to the compiler? am I missing something?

Comment: if you are on the command line, then use `./myProgram first second third`. What OS are you using? Which shell?

Comment: You don't need the `g++` compiler to run your binary, you need it to make a binary out of the C++ source code and then, you'll better use `g++ Wall -g`

Comment: I also don't get it! That looks pretty unusual, WTH is `./myProgram` in this context?? g++ is used for compiling C++ source code usually ...

Comment: Sorry, I'm not putting g++ in front of it. I made a mistake, I'll edit the question. I'm quite new to C++.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The command line args to your executable should just be seperated by spaces.

```
<?php
    echo exec('myProgram arg1 arg2 arg3');
?>
```

If your arguments are numbers etc... then you convert them to a string and pass that string to the exec command. C/C++ only accept string arguments in their main functions.

Comment: Great, thanks Dennis, this is what I was looking for. One last thing. How do I retrieve those arguments in the C program?

Comment: @MartCoul The binary produced from C programme takes them as `argv[1]` to `argv[argc-1]`, if your `main` is declared `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`. Note that it gets them as strings, so any parsing would have to be done in the C programme.

Answer (score 1):

You may need to have a look on how to compile code using compiler

Probably this may help:
http://homepages.gac.edu/~mc38/2001J/documentation/g++.html

Then you may run it by calling executable and the arguments something like

> ./prog arguments